# Loop over pandas dataframe and group by data

Tags: python, pandas, windows

I want to filter my data according to a specific number, in a column. And then I want to group by the rows from the filter. To that I did this code:

```
df_data=pd.DataFrame(df_)
for values_in_columns in df_.itertuples(name=None):
    if values_in_columns[10] == 1:
        count_data_oneDay=df_.groupby([df_['Data'].dt.date])['ValueAnalysisPerDay'].sum()
```

However in this way, the cycle doesn't end and the values grouped aren't filtered, meaning that the result of the grouped data are all the rows.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need filter 11th column by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) before aggregate `sum`, loops by `itertuples` here are not necessary:

```
df_ = df_data[df_data.iloc[:, 10] == 1]
df1 = df_.groupby([df_['Data'].dt.date])['ValueAnalysisPerDay'].sum()
```